# Create fresh Rails 5 credentials on clone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

**Problem**
I am creating a [rails 5.2 template](https://github.com/mklemme/rails-template). I've created a new project which is a [fork](https://github.com/invisible-hats/gra-app) of the template. I don't want to use the same `config/master.key` since this would be shared across `X` other projects. Is there a way to generate a new key & `config/credentials.yml.enc` pair? That way I could include a `config/credentials.yml.enc.sample` and they run `rails credentials:new` or something then copy the contents over?

Can't find anything in the documentation or google/so searches about this and my alternative is to use the same key across all my public projects :,(

Answer (score 8):

as described here: https://blog.eq8.eu/til/rails-52-credentials-tricks.html

Regenerate key

Currently there is no “edit password” feature, you need copy original content of the credentials, remove the enc files and regenerate fresh credentials file (source)

- step 1 copy content of original credentials rails credentials:show
- step 2 move your config/credentials.yml.enc and config/master.key away (mv config/credentials.yml.enc ./tmp/ && mv config/master.key ./tmp/)
- step 3 run EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit
- step 4 paste copied values from original credentials
- step 5 save and commit config/credentials.yml.enc

note! `EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit` may not work if you require credential value in some file (e.g. in `config/database.yml`)

Comment: If it's still not working after trying the steps above, try removing lines like `/config/master.key` or`/config/credentials/production.key` that are related to credentials in `.gitignore` file. Also, you might need to run `rails credential:edit` in a new terminal tab. (This is in addition to commenting out all the lines that include `Rails.application.credentials...` in your code.)

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/commands/credentials/USAGE

> For applications created prior to Rails 5.2, we'll automatically
>   generate a new credentials file in `config/credentials.yml.enc` the
>   first time you run `bin/rails credentials:edit`. If you didn't have a
>   master key saved in `config/master.key`, that'll be created too.

So I can create a plain text version of the encrypted file to show which keys are required:

> foo_api_key: 123

They run `bin/rails credentials:edit` which generates the key and encrypted file then they copy the keys over to add them to the encrypted file.

Answer (score 1):

Using @Myk Klemme's answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/48373368/936494 I was able to successfully re-generate credential files `config/credentials.yml.enc`, `config/master.key`.

For that I first removed the existing `config/credentials.yml.enc` file I got from cloned template-repo and then ran following command

```
rails_new_app$ EDITOR="mate --wait" bin/rails credentials:edit
```

which generated following output:

```
Adding config/master.key to store the encryption key: <encryption_key>

Save this in a password manager your team can access.

If you lose the key, no one, including you, can access anything encrypted with it.

      create  config/master.key


File encrypted and saved.
```